# c# convert a string into JSON like TreeView

Tags: c#, treenode

i have a string that looks like this:

> "es_apiResponse":{"es_evaluationTruncation":false,"es_queryE
>   valuationTime":1,"es_totalResults":30676,"es_totalResultsTyp
>   e":"estimated","es_numberOfAvailableResults":500,"es_numberO
>   fEstimatedResults":30676,"es_query":{"role":"request","sear
>   chTerms":"yonic"}}*

that means it has one or more objects inside it. this is what i came up so far but i got lost in the code

check each caracter in a string
if char is a "," than add a new line in current node
if char is an open "{" -> open a new child node with the name given by the previos word (if string builder is build to generate a intermediate string than this can be used to get the name for the node ithout the commas)
if the char is "}" ->close the curent node.

Note 1 --> should I keep track of open nodes ?

```
    TreeNode StringToTree(string convertME, string treeNodeName)
    {
        TreeNode treeNode = new TreeNode();
        string NodeName = treeNodeName;
        string converted = convertME;
        string tempname = null;
        int i = 0;
        char c;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int len = convertME.Length;
        convertME.Replace(',','\n');
        for (i = 0; i == len; i++)
        {

            if (converted.ElementAt(i) == 44)
            {
                {tempname}.Nodes.Add(sb.ToString());
                sb.Length = 0;
            }
            if (converted.ElementAt(i) == 123)
            {

                tempname = sb.ToString().Replace("\"", "");
                {NodeName}.Nodes.Add(tempname);
                sb.Length = 0;

            }
            if (converted.ElementAt(i) == 125)
            {
                {tempname}.Nodes.Add(sb.ToString());
                sb.Length = 0;
            }

            sb.Append(convertME.ElementAt(i));
        }
        return {tempname};
```

there is one other error in my code --> i don't know how to assign name to variables that come from strings like here:

```
                tempname = sb.ToString().Replace("\"", "");
                {NodeName}.Nodes.Add(tempname);
```

Comment: If it is JSON or xml (and a couple of other supported formats)  you can use newtonsoft / json.net nuget package and use JSONConvert.Deserialize(yourstring);

Comment: and the other way around works too, if you have a string or object you want to serialize TO json/xml/etc. use the serialize function :p

Comment: @Daan I am not controling the way strings come in I am only in charge of the output. But thank you, i will defentely have a look at that